# Responsive JavaFX fxml dentro de otro fxml, adaptar Pane interno según se actualiza

Tags: java, javafx, responsive, scenebuilder, fxml

**Contexto:** Aplicación visual con login y pantalla de menú con opciones al lateral.

**Problema:** Lo tengo en el menú principal ya que lo que he hecho es tener una única ventana con un fxml con todos los botones a modo de menu lateral, cada vez que se pulsa uno se abre otro fxml dentro de un Pane pero sin actualizar el fxml del menú. Lo que no consigo es que los fxml internos sean responsive, en si el Pane que los recibe, porque el fxml del menú, si es responsive.
No se si me explico bien pero aquí dejo unas fotos de los archivos existentes y como se ve la aplicación.

**Programas:** Eclipse, Scenebuilder.

[image: Controladores y .fxml de vistas]

**Menú:** Esto es la vista del menú, en la que están los botones para cargar los fxml de cada opción en el Pane.

[image: Vista de menú]

**Aplicación en menú, seleccionado 2 botón:** Aquí podéis ver la aplicación, lo que son los botones laterales no hay ningún problema responsive, únicamente en el Pane interior que siempre tiene el mismo tamaño.

[image: Aplicación funcionando]

**Aclaración:** Todo funciona perfectamente, únicamente no consigo que sea responsive esa parte, cualquier recomendación es bien recibida, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar un scrollPane para tal fin....y ajustar las dimensiones al agregar el nuevo fxml. Generalmente usando los get para obtener las dimensiones del anchorPane de los nuevos FXML lo puedes usar de parametros para establecer la dimension del ScrollPane. O activar la opcion de Pannable para que puedas navegar dentro de la interfaz que agreguez sim importar la dimension.

Answer (score 0):

**Pasar referencias de objetos como argumentos entre clases controladoras de archivos fxml**

Demostración del programa . se carga un archivo fxml hijo y este puede acceder a los nodos del fxml padre
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al inyectar el archivo  fxml se puede obtener la instancia de su clase controlador con el método `getController()` de [FXMLoader](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) que retorna el controlador asociado al objeto raíz , pero antes hay que cargarlo con `load()` para evitar recibir `null` de `getController()` .
Aquí hay un ejemplo con todas los archivos  .java y .fxml

**App.java**

Inicio de la aplicación , va a cargar el archivo root.fxml y lanzar la ventana

```
 public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("root.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**root.fxml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controllerparam.RootController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toLeafGreen" text="cargar leafGreen.fxml" />
        <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="61.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toLeafRed" text="cargar leafRed.fxml" />
        <AnchorPane fx:id="leafHolder" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="303.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="297.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
        <TextField fx:id="rootText" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="188.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**RootController.java**

Aquí hay dos métodos `toLeafGreen()` y `toLeafRed()` cada uno es llamado por botones que están en root.fxml  .Ambos van a cargar e inyectar otro archivo fxml  que va a ser parte de la misma ventana para tener acceso a sus controladores con el objeto `loader` . Ambos métodos regresan sus respectivos controladores con `loader.getController();` . Una vez obtenida una referencia del controlador  se puede pasar por argumento cualquier objeto de RootController que es la clase controlador de root.fxml a cualquiera de sus dos fxml hijos . En este caso `rootText` que es de tipo `TextField`.

```
 public class RootController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private AnchorPane leafHolder;
    @FXML private  TextField rootText;

    @FXML
    private void toLeafGreen(Event event) throws IOException {

        leafHolder.getChildren().clear();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("leafGreen.fxml"));
        Node node = loader.load();
        LeafGreenController leafGreenController = loader.getController();
        leafGreenController.bindRootText(rootText);
        leafHolder.getChildren().add(node);

    }

    @FXML
    private void toLeafRed(Event event) throws IOException {
        
        leafHolder.getChildren().clear();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("leafRed.fxml"));
        Node node = loader.load();
        LeafRedController leafRedController = loader.getController();
        leafRedController.bindRootText(rootText);

        leafHolder.getChildren().add(node);

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

**leafGrenController.java** y **leafRedController.java**

Ambos reciben a `rootText` de `rootController` en el parámetro del método `bindRootText()` . Aqui se puede manipular un objeto del fxml padre en el fxml hijo (también se puede hacer al revés ). En este caso se sincronizan bidireccionalmente los textos mediante `redText.textProperty().bindBidirectional(rootText.textProperty());` y `greenText.textProperty().bindBidirectional(rootText.textProperty());`

```
    public class LeafRedController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML private TextField redText;

    public void bindRootText(TextField rootText) {
        
    redText.textProperty().bindBidirectional(rootText.textProperty());
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
       
    }    

    
}
```

y

```
    public class LeafGreenController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML private TextField greenText;
    

    public void bindRootText(TextField rootText) {
        greenText.textProperty().bindBidirectional(rootText.textProperty());
    }

    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        
    }    

    
}
```

**leafGreen.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controllerparam.LeafGreenController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="greenText" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

**leafRed.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controllerparam.LeafRedController">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="redText" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```